# Spring hibernate what @param gonna map to

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have this Pojo as my hibernate entity, I am trying to use hibernate to update some rows in my table:

```
@Entity
public class Money {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "userid")
    private String userid;

    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;

    @Column(name = "money")
    private double money;

    @Column(name = "status")
    private String status;

    @Column(name = "group_transaction_id")
    private String group_transaction_id;


    @Column(name = "item_transaction_id")
    private String item_transaction_id;

    @Column(name = "created_at")
    @CreationTimestamp
    private Date createdAt;

    @Column(name = "updated_at")
    private Date updated_at;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getUserid() {
        return userid;
    }

    public void setUserid(String userid) {
        this.userid = userid;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public double getMoney() {
        return money;
    }

    public void setMoney(double money) {
        this.money = money;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }    

    public Date getCreatedAt() {
        return createdAt;
    }

    public void setCreatedAt(Date createdAt) {
        this.createdAt = createdAt;
    }

    public Date getUpdated_at() {
        return updated_at;
    }

    public void setUpdated_at(Date updated_at) {
        this.updated_at = updated_at;
    }

}
```

What I am trying to do is:

```
@Repository
public interface MoneyRepository extends CrudRepository<Winners, Long> {

    List<Winners> findAll();

    List<Winners> findByUseridAndStatus(String userid, String status);

    @Modifying(clearAutomatically = true)
    @Transactional
    @Query(value = "UPDATE Money w SET w.status = :status WHERE id in :ids")
    int testUpdate(@Param("status") String status, @Param("id") List<Long> ids);
}
```

And in my Controller/Service I am using it like:

```
@Autowired
PayoutRepository payoutRepository;

public int testUpdateDB() {

    List<Long> pendingIds = Arrays.asList(1l, 2l);

    int affected = payoutRepository.testUpdate("pending", pendingIds);

        return affected;
    }
```

If I don't use  `@Param("id") List<Long> ids` it's complaining about

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: For queries with named parameters you
>   need to use provide names for method parameters. Use @Param for query
>   method parameters, or when on Java 8+ use the javac flag -parameters.

If I use `@Param("id") List<Long> ids` it's complaining :

> org.hibernate.QueryException: Named parameter [ids] not set

And if change my query to `@Query(value = "UPDATE Money w SET w.status = :status WHERE id in :id")` without changing anything else (just changed :ids to :id) it works. Can some explain how that mapping works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@Param("id")` tells him the name of the parameter in your query

So it should be `@Param("ids")` if your query is `"UPDATE Money w SET w.status = :status WHERE id in :ids"`

```
If I don't use  @Param("id") List<Long> ids it's complaining about

java.lang.IllegalStateException: For queries with named parameters you need to use provide names for method parameters. Use @Param for query method parameters, or when on Java 8+ use the javac flag -parameters.
```

It's because you need to have a @param for all your paramter to tell him where to map which parameters.

```
If I use @Param("id") List<Long> ids it's complaining :

org.hibernate.QueryException: Named parameter [ids] not set
```

It's because now you have a @param annotation so it proceed on and then it does not find any param named id `:id` in your query `@Query`

The name in @Param annotation should map the name of the parameter in your query, name after the `:`